# Typo3 show every user his specific files

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

i want to show any logged in user, his specific uploaded files like contracts an so on. Is there any way without extensions?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no built-in / core view to show "my" files.

Answer (score 0):

As @Christian said, there is no such functionality implemented to the core. However, you can archive your needs by extending `sys_file_reference`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707802/extending-sys-file-reference-fal), in the QUESTION you have your ANSWER!.

Keep this solution in mind to get value as well! see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39717903/5961782

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear whether you mean front end or back end users.

for BE users:
give every BE-user it's own filespace, so each one can only upload files to his space, which only he can see.

for FE user:
as there is no field where you can add files to the fe_user record you need some further fields to realize the relation between file and user. this can be done only with an extension.

you might avoid a new field if you store the information in the filesystem:
for every fe_user you use a folder like `fileadmin/users/123` where `123` is the uid of the user. but to be sure noone can read files from others (by guessing their uid) you need to protect these folders.
One option is to use a hash instead of the naked `uid`.

Now you need to make sure that uploaded files or user specific generated files are stored in the folder of the user. This handling probably is not possible without an extension.